# Django Filter Not Returning Right Results

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

I have a view where I am trying to filter a product by category.

```
class ProductListView(ListView):
    context_object_name = 'products'
    model = models.Product
    template_name = "catalogue/catalogue.html"
    products = Product.objects.filter(category__name="Biryani Dishes")
```

So I have a category called 'Biryani Dishes'. I get the error ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'Biryani Dishes'

If I change the query to (name='Chicken Biryani') I get back all the products. (I am expecting just Chicken Biryani).

Ideally, I would like to create a generic query that takes in the category as an argument and I can specify the actual name on the HTML template.

Any help is really appreciated.

Models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse

class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, db_index=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=200, db_index=True, unique=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('name',)
        verbose_name = 'category'
        verbose_name_plural = 'categories'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    # def get_absolute_url(self):
    #     return reverse('shop:product_list_by_category', args=[self.slug])

class Product(models.Model):
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, related_name='products')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, db_index=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=200, db_index=True)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
    available = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('-created',)
        index_together = (('id', 'slug'),)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    # def get_absolute_url(self):
    #     return reverse('shop:product_detail', args=[self.id, self.slug])
```

template code:

```
            {% for product in products %}
            <tr>
                <td><h5>{{ product.name }}</h5>
                <p>Cooked with chicken and mutton cumin spices</p></td>
                <td><p><strong>£ {{ product.price }}</strong></p></td>
                <td class="options"><a href="#0"><i class="icon_plus_alt2"></i></a></td>
            </tr>
            {% endfor %}
```

Comment: Can you post your  models.py as well?

Comment: Just posted models.py

Comment: You probably wanted `category__name = "..."`.

Comment: To piggyback what @internet_user said, I would make the following adjustment: `birdish = products.filter(category__name="Biryani Dishes")`. This will search by the name of the Category. Additionally, you will save yourself from hitting the database a second time, since you already get the queryset in your `products` variable.

Comment: This returns products from all categories. I have added the code from my template aswell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Queryset needs to be defined, instead of product which is why it was returning all the records.

```
class ProductListView(ListView):
    context_object_name = 'products'
    model = models.Product
    template_name = "catalogue/catalogue.html"
    queryset = Product.objects.filter(category__name="Biryani Dishes")
```

Answer (score 1):

You should change `category` by `category__name`. So you would have:

```
class ProductListView(ListView):
    context_object_name = 'products'
    model = models.Product
    template_name = "catalogue/catalogue.html"
    products  = Product.objects.all()
    birdish = Product.objects.filter(category__name="Biryani Dishes")
```

You can only filter by `category` if the variable to compare is the `pk` or an instance of the model itself.

Comment: This returns all the products from the DB, not just the specific category. I have added the template code aswell now.

Comment: It is because you are iterating over `products` instead of `birdish`.

Comment: Replace `products  = Product.objects.all()` to `products = Product.objects.filter(category__name="Biryani Dishes")` and that's might be the result you want.

Comment: I changed the code and I am still getting all the products, not just my filtered ones.

Comment: Is this anything to do with setting context_object_name = 'products' ?